# Export image from GEE without accidental resample?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, digital-image-processing

I'm trying to export an ALOS DSM raster at its native 30m resolution for a specific region derived from a centroid in GEE. I'm noticing, however, that when I open the raster in ArcGIS there is a clear waffle pattern where the same value was clearly written for two adjacent cells. My guess is that this is because the export is sampling a new 30x30 raster according to the specified region, rather than exporting a clip of the image at its original resolution.

[image: ALOS DSM Markup]

Can anyone help explain what is happening here? And does anyone have a solution for exporting an image for a specified region in GEE that preserves original resolution?

My code here:

```
var oasis = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([8.979249,34.341562])));

var bounding_box_func = function(feature) {
  var intermediate_buffer = feature.buffer(5000);
  var intermediate_box = intermediate_buffer.bounds();
    return(intermediate_box);
};

var oasisBox = oasis.map(bounding_box_func);
var oasisCoords = oasisBox.geometry().coordinates().get(0);
var oasisGeom = ee.Geometry.Polygon(oasisCoords)

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('JAXA/ALOS/AW3D30/V3_2');
var elevation = dataset.select('DSM');
var medDSM = elevation.reduce(ee.Reducer.median());
var oasisDSM = medDSM.clip(oasisBox);

var DSMVis = {
  min: 200,
  max: 1200,
  palette: ['0000ff', '00ffff', 'ffff00', 'ff0000', 'ffffff']
};

Map.centerObject(oasisBox);
Map.addLayer(oasisDSM, DSMVis);

var dataLink = medDSM.getDownloadURL( {name: 'El Guettar_ALOSdsm', bands: 'DSM_median', scale: 30, region: oasisGeom} );
```

When the last line is run without any {scale:} argument I get the following raster of two giant cells as below (pink box is the area of interest):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you care down to the sub-pixel, don't use scale; it only approximates the original image's resolution due to floating point issues, etc.  Instead, specify the exact projection that the (closest) image is using:

```
var first = dataset.filterBounds(oasis).first()
var dataLink = medDSM.getDownloadURL( {
  name: 'El Guettar_ALOSdsm', 
  bands: 'DSM_median', 
  crs: first.projection(), 
  region: oasisGeom
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help - I tried your edit in my script and ended up with a raster export with only two giant cells. I've edited my post with the image of my result in ArcGIS. Do you have any ideas for this new issue?

Comment: Maybe you forgot to include the crs?

Comment: I checked again to make sure I included the crs and I got the same result. Could it have something to do with the missing scale argument?